# MySql bit columns returns weird large number in PHP 7.1 (not in previous versions)

Tags: php, mysql

I am testing my PHP site developed with PHP 5.5 to see if it is compatible with PHP 7.1 and I found a very strange problem.

The problem is that doing a simple select on a table with a BIT(1) column returns an 18 digit number instead of a 0 / 1 that return previous PHP versions.

The problematic version is PHP 7.1.9, the other versions I tried that work OK are 5.5.12 and 7.0.23. All of the test were conducted on WAMP 2.5 with Apache 2.4.9 and MySQL 5.6.17.

Here is a minimun set of code to replicate it.

Create table and initial data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_bit`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_bit` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bit_col` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  `varchar_col` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO test_bit (bit_col, varchar_col)
VALUES (1, 'hello'), (0, 'world'), (TRUE, 'how'), (FALSE, 'are'), (NULL, 'you?');
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test_db");
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM test_bit");
$rs = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rs[] = $row;
}
var_dump($rs);
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Here are the results in PHP 5.5 and 7.0

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '1' (length=1)
      'varchar_col' => string 'hello' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '0' (length=1)
      'varchar_col' => string 'world' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '1' (length=1)
      'varchar_col' => string 'how' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '0' (length=1)
      'varchar_col' => string 'are' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '0' (length=1)
      'varchar_col' => string 'you?' (length=4)
```

And here is the result in PHP 7.1

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '326352660489830401' (length=18)
      'varchar_col' => string 'hello' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '326352866648260608' (length=18)
      'varchar_col' => string 'world' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '326353072806690817' (length=18)
      'varchar_col' => string 'how' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '326353278965121024' (length=18)
      'varchar_col' => string 'are' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      'bit_col' => string '326353485123551232' (length=18)
      'varchar_col' => string 'you?' (length=4)
```

The numbers in the 'bit_col' in PHP 7.1 change the first one or two times I set PHP 7.1 as my server version and then stay the same (until I change to 7.0 or 5.5 and then come back to 7.1 again). They seem like a timestamp or something of the sort.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: That sounds very odd. I can't think of any reason why this would happen, if you run the *exact* same code, just with different PHP versions. PHP doesn't really care for the type of column (`VARCHAR` vs `BIT` for example), so it doesn't know that it returns a bit per se, it just fetches the value in the column - but it shouldn't mangle the value like that. You said they change for every time you re-run this code in PHP 7.1.9?

Comment: @Qirel it is not exactly every time. It seems that it changes the first one or two times I run the script in PHP7.1. If I change to another version (ex 7.0) and then come back to 7.1 it changes again the first one or two times and then remains in those numbers, fixed. The code is EXACTLY the same, I only change the PHP version and I get the different results shown in the question.

Comment: I'm quite intrigued, and I don't really know what could cause such an issue. You don't happen to run the two versions at the same time?

Comment: @Quirel I couldn't even if I wanted to. I am using WAMP so I have to choose which PHP version it is running. It is not possible to run two versions simultaneously. I also use a phpinfo to make sure that each test is with the appropriate version. If you have any idea of anything I could try, please let me know, this seems like too big of an issue to have been missed by the PHP developers.

Comment: There's no logical relation between the two numbers, so I honestly have no idea. As I said, I'm quite intrigued, I'll be following this question to see if someone has an answer ;-) I don't have any tools available on this system right now to reproduce the issue either.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue on PHP 7.1.8 + MariaDB (Windows 10 + xampp). The numbers change after restarting apache.

Comment: Same issue with PDO.

Comment: I spun up some test containers for PHP 7.1.[89] and MariaDB 10.2 and did not encounter the issue. I would wager that it's something to do with the Windows builds of one or the other.

Comment: Also that last set of values in the INSERT violates the `NOT NULL` constraint set in the table definition.

Comment: @Sammitch the NULL was on purpose to test the default FALSE value when retrieving it.

Answer (score 5):

It is in fact an already reported issue in PHP since August the 1st.

PHP [Bug #75018](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75018)

It seems to be only for the Windows Platform as some comments have suggested.

Comment: Good spot. I am going to change my bits to tinyints, best solution I can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Today I faced with the same issue on armv7.

According to bug [#75018](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75018) and related [commit](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blobdiff;f=ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c;h=0b2039c5c3eb66c125e8908cef4d2dbbccd7635d;hp=90ae615a1a72eb7cd3de7f0ec59aeb45298fc6d5;hb=3d93856c4a05394196c5610ae11cf019d1e18f76;hpb=c24b3eff110dafbdb980d3ebfc20db575cfec519) I've fixed mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c, recompiled PHP and now it works as expected.

So solution is:

- wait for new PHP version (with fix)
- compile latest PHP from sources applying required fix